# Node.js Paypal integration

Tags: node.js, paypal, discord.js

I am trying to implement paypal into my discord bot (discord.js) Basically I am looking to generate a sale/order for X amount and await either have a command to check if the order was paid or just await until the order is paid.

Are there any modules or apis that would allow me to create the order and proceed/return a promise when the order is paid?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation from paypal itself: [Paypal-docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/server-side/node/) there is step by step guide how to create a transaction. As for how to check if a transaction was successfull take a look at the braintree docs: [Braintree-docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/node?source=developer.paypal.com#result-object)